# Sort 1st and 3rd level of a multidimensional array by keys

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, key

I have this multidimensional array, called `$rent`:

```
Array
(
    [product2] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [2013-07-25] => 2
                    [2013-07-23] => 1
                    [2013-07-21] => 3
                )

        )

    [product3] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [2013-07-24] => 5
                    [2013-07-22] => 4
                    [2013-07-20] => 3
                )

        )

    [product1] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [2013-07-29] => 1
                    [2013-07-28] => 2
                    [2013-07-27] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

I'd like to do a double sort:

1. First, by productX ascending
2. Then, for each product, by date of rent ascending

So that the resulting array would be:

```
Array
(
    [product1] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [2013-07-27] => 2
                    [2013-07-28] => 2
                    [2013-07-29] => 1
                )

        )

    [product2] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [2013-07-21] => 3
                    [2013-07-23] => 1
                    [2013-07-25] => 2
                )

        )

    [product3] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [2013-07-20] => 3
                    [2013-07-22] => 4
                    [2013-07-24] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

How can I reach this? Many thanks in advance

Comment: I tried array_multisort($rent), nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ksort($rent);
foreach($rent as &$item) {
    ksort($item['dates']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply **[ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)** the products, then iterate through them and use the same for the dates key.

```
ksort($products);

foreach($products as &$product)
    ksort($product['dates']);
```

Where `$products` is the array you showed us. Note that you need to pass the value in the foreach loop as a reference (using the `&` operator) otherwise the changes won't be updated in the original array.

Comment: this works with another "ksort" instead of "asort" (and of course with $rent as original array, as I stated): thanks

Comment: What? There isn't `asort` in there.

Comment: There was an asort($product['dates']); some minutes ago: did you edited the answer? Or my eyes are just too tired? :-)

Answer (score 1):

for my understanding of your problem; Nadh solution is almost there. but i believe you want ksort()

this is my corrections to Nadh answer

```
ksort($rent);

foreach($rent as $product => $dates) {
    ksort($rent[$product]['dates']);
}

print_r($rent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, the 2nd level in your data structure doesn't require ksort()ing, it doesn't hurt to sort the single-element level, so recursion can be used as a general purpose utility.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OFM2H))

```
function rksort(&$array)
{
    ksort($array);
    foreach ($array as &$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            (__FUNCTION__)($v);
        }
    }
}
rksort($array);
var_export($array);
```

---

As for your narrow requirements, I think the only approach that wasn't already posted was to sort the `dates` data by reference via array destructuring syntax. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tIak4))

```
ksort($array);
foreach ($array as ['dates' => &$dates]) {
    ksort($dates);
}
var_export($array);
```